# Problem with POST header in Java REST WS

Tags: java, rest, dispatcher

I'm trying to a write simple REST Java web-service. I use Provider interface on the server side and Dispatch on the clients. I'm trying to transmit a value in header of POST request but there is some problem.
My client code:

```
private void invoke(Dispatch<Source> dispatch
                    Object data) {
    Map<String, Object> request_context = dispatch.getRequestContext();
    request_context.put(MessageContext.HTTP_REQUEST_METHOD, "POST");

    request_context.put("org.kpi.asd", "SOME TEXT");        

    StreamSource source = make_stream_source(data.toString());
    dispatch.invoke(source);
}
```

My server code:

```
public Source invoke(Source request) {
    // Filter on the HTTP request verb
    if (ws_ctx == null) throw new RuntimeException("DI failed on ws_ctx.");

    // Grab the message context and extract the request verb.
    MessageContext msg_ctx = ws_ctx.getMessageContext();      
    String aaa = (String) msg_ctx.get("org.kpi.asd");
}
```

On server: aaa is null. I can't understand why. Help me, please (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the message context is not where you set arbitrary http headers.  there is another property in the message context which contains the http headers, see [HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/handler/MessageContext.html#HTTP_REQUEST_HEADERS).